# result by AJAX not selectable

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

The following code will give me all records using AJAX request as intended. Unfortunately, I am not able to take one selected record into form. I just can select them, not take them(Look at my attachment, please). I assume some error in `templateResult` or `templateSelection`.

**Rephrasing question**:
'can't select' means, that I am not able to adopt one single record- beeing displayed- into formular. It's like food for a dog which can't be eaten by the dog,'cause hand will be moved away again and again...
Hope this helped understanding my question.
P.S.:id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_1 is Propertie of model

Here is code of formular:

```
$url = \yii\helpers\Url::to ( [ 'berufe' ] );
    ?><?=
    $form->field ( $model , 'id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_1' , [ 'addon' => [
            'prepend' => [ 'content' => 'gelernter Beruf 1' ] ] ] )->widget ( \kartik\widgets\Select2::classname () , [
        'options' => [ 'placeholder' => 'Berufe suchen ...' ] ,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true ,
            'minimumInputLength' => 3 ,
            'language' => [
                'errorLoading' => new JsExpression ( "function () { return 'Waiting for results...'; }" ) ,
            ] ,
            'ajax' => [
                'url' => $url ,
                'dataType' => 'json' ,
                'data' => new JsExpression ( 'function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }' )
            ] ,
            'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression ( 'function (markup) { return markup; }' ) ,
            'templateResult' => new JsExpression ( 'function(id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_1) { return id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_1.text; }' ) ,
            'templateSelection' => new JsExpression ( 'function (id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_1) { return id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_1.text; }' ) ,
        ] ,
    ] )->label ( false );
```

Here is ControllerCode which works pretty fine

```
public function actionBerufe( $q = null , $id = null ) {
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $out = [ 'results' => [ 'id' => '' , 'text' => '' ] ];
    if ( !is_null ( $q ) ) {
        $query = new \yii\db\Query();
        $query->select ( 'ID, Bezeichnung_neutral_kurz  AS text' )
                ->from ( 'yii2_ba.ba_berufe' )
                ->where ( [ 'like' , 'Bezeichnung_neutral_kurz' , $q ] )
                ->limit ( 20 );
        $command = $query->createCommand ();
        $data = $command->queryAll ();
        $out['results'] = array_values ( $data );
    } elseif ( $id > 0 ) {
        $out['results'] = [ 'id' => $id , 'text' => \common\modules\basis\models\BaBerufe::find ( $id )->Bezeichnung_neutral_kurz ];
    }
    return $out;
}
```

[image]

Comment: it's really hard to understand what problem you are having, maybe try to rephrase your question? what do you mean by I cant select ? are you trying to say that after clicking on any option inside the `Select2` should populate the form with the information related to that record

Comment: Question has been rephrased